# Javascript: global variable inside of a function

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Im a beginner trying to create a responsive HTML-Sidenav. I want to change a value of a global variable 
inside of a function. After that i want to use the variable again as if condition for Portrait or Landscape-Scale, to get the Sidenav working as i want.
Thank you for your effort. Is it possible to use an "updated" variable for the Portait or Landscape if conditions after rotating the device? Or are there any other solutions?

```
    /* window-orientation to var and getting updated by orientation change */
    window.ori = Math.abs(window.orientation); /* write changedorientation*/

    /* Portrait scale */
    if (ori === 0 || ori === 180) {
        /* Portrait-Sidenav */
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "100%";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "calc(100% - 30px)";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "0px"; /* excl. Top-Nav space */
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0%";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = 'none'
            document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
            document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "35px"; /* incl. Top-Nav space */
        }
    }

    /* Landscape scale */
    if (ori === 90 || ori === -90) {
        /* Landscape-Sidenav */
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "35%";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "calc(35% - 20px)";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("openNav").className = 'topnav-hide';
            document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "0px"; /* excl. Top-Nav space */
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("openNav").className = 'topnav';
            document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "35px"; /* incl. Top-Nav space */
        }
    }

    /* onorientationchanges for responsiv Sidenav */
    window.onorientationchange = function () { 
        /* write current orientation in var */
        window.ori = Math.abs(window.orientation); /* just working in this funktion */
        /* Sidenav to var */
        var x = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

        if ((ori === 90 || ori === -90) && x.offsetWidth > 0 && x.offsetHeight > 0) {
        /* you are now in Landscape */
        document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "35%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "calc(35% - 20px)";
        document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "0px"; /* excl. Top-Nav space */
        }

        if ((ori === 0 || ori === 180) && x.offsetWidth > 0 && x.offsetHeight > 0) {
        /* you are now in Portrait */
        document.getElementById("Main").style.marginLeft = "100%";
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "calc(100% - 30px)";
        document.getElementById("Main").style.top = "35px"; /* incl. Top-Nav space */
        }
    };
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: Note that the function declarations you have in `if` statements *may not work as you intend* on all browsers due to hoisting. [Block scoped function declarations](http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedFunctions) were introduced in ES6. In ES5 you'd get the *last* function declaration. In ES6, they won't be global.

Comment: Also, `Math.abs` will only return positive values or a zero, so `ori === -90` is a useless check.

Comment: opening the navigation after window orientation changed doesn't work correctly because im changing the ori variable just inside the function. But i want to use this changed variable outside the function to open or close the navigation correctly.

Comment: how can i change the variable value global?

Answer (score 0):

> Or are there any other solutions?

YES use [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and CSS grid.